# Anyway to use try_files instead rewrite rule "example.com/index.php/*.*" use file form "example.com/*.*" on nginx

Tags: nginx

I got 404 when trying to getting file info example.com/index.php/media/*.js because the file is in example.com/media/*.js

I use rewrite rule and it work normaly like

```
location /index.php/media/ {
    rewrite /index.php/(.*) /$1 permanent;
}
```

But I dont want to redirect url and just want use try_files rule to get directly file . Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Why not use an alias?

Comment: How to use alias?

Comment: Try `rewrite...last` instead of `rewrite...permanent` if you want an internal redirect.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried `alias /home/example.com/public_html/media` and `rewrite .... last` and got same result it mean any code in two of above is ok (same) right?

Comment: They both have the same effect, although `alias` should be a little bit faster, since it doesn't need regex matching.